# django template extends base but base has variables to show

Tags: django, templates, inheritance

I have some templates set up for my app, which extend a base template but the base template has variables in it (a list of items in the footer). Currently I am getting these variables in the views.py method for my app by importing the footerApp and then getting the items and passing them to the context to render out with the variables for this app. Surly that can;t be right. Is there a way to automatically call methods that a view needs when it's template is called?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind! I found [this](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/jun/14/django-tips-template-context-processors/) template.

Comment: I still don't get it. How would the views.py be written? changing c = Context({})
  return render_to_response('pages/index.html', c, context_instance=RequestContext(request)) to RequestContext(request, {})
  return render_to_response('pages/index.html', c, context_instance=RequestContext(request)) doesn't do anything differently for me.